# Unexpected Python for-loop behaviour?

Tags: python

Can someone explain what happened in the **second run** ? Why did I get a stream of 9's when the code should have given an error?

```
>>> for __ in range(10): #first run
...     print(__)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

This was the **second run**

```
>>> for __ in range(10): #second run
...     print(_)
...
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
>>> exit()
```

After this, when I ran the code for the third time, the same code executed as expected and gave the below error. I realize that this question has no practical use. But, I would really like to know why it happened?

```
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_` variable is set in the Python interpreter, always holding the last non-`None` result of any expression statement that has been run.

From the [*Reserved Classifiers and Identifiers* reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> The special identifier `_` is used in the interactive interpreter to store the result of the last evaluation; it is stored in the `builtins` module.

and from [`sys.displayhook()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook):

> If value is not `None`, this function prints `repr(value)` to `sys.stdout`, and saves value in `builtins._`. [...] `sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression) entered in an interactive Python session.

Here, that result was `9`, from an expression you must have run before the code you shared.

The `NameError` indicates you restarted the Python interpreter and did not yet run an expression statement yet that produced a non-`None` value:

```
>>> _
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_' is not defined
>>> 3 * 3
9
>>> _
9
```